# Conditions In Routes.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Sorry guys i am new in Laravel.
**I want to use conditions in Routes.php using laravel 5.2** 
When the User is logged i want to call the showExperience function else redirect to login

**My routes.php code**

```
Route::get('/profile', function () {
if (Auth::check()) {

    $url = action('ProfilesController@showExperience');
    return redirect($url);
} else {
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
});
```

**here is My ProfilesController.php**

```
public function showExperience(){
       $data = Experience::all();

    return view('profile')->with('experienceData',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) for this purpose

for example:

```
Route::get('/profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'YourController@index']);
```

Then you can go to `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` and `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` to change default redirect values

Comment: Thanks @Mister M . I have got the answer exactly the way you answer.

Comment: No problem. Also, please consider accepting my answer then.

Comment: I am trying but it says that your reputations is not more than 15 to publicly show your vote

Answer (score 0):

Here is My Solution

```
Route::get('/profile',[
                        'uses' => 'ProfilesController@showExperience',
                        'as' => 'profile',
                        'middleware' => 'auth'
                              ]);
```